# How to create a new directory inside other directory multiple times using ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, recursion, directory

I'am new in programming on iOS and I need to make an app. I've tried with NSFileManager and UITableViewController but I am still nowhere. Here is what i want to do:

Screen 1 - This is my homescreen;

Screen 2 -  Then I need to create new directory with new UITableViewController and Core Data to store image and text information inside it;

Screen 3 - And inside the second directory I need to create a new one like the previous and then the same thing until it reaches the memory limit;

You can find the images here:

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0ByHA4Is_eLoMRlhCYTM2QU9kZVk&usp=sharing

Can you give me any advice please .

Many thanks in advance!
I am sorry if my question isn't clear enough! Just ask what you don't understand and I will try to explain more.

Edit:
I will fill the directories with images!

Comment: It's completely unclear what you want to do. You mention `NSFileManager` and multiple directories and then later mention CoreData. Pick one and stick with it. I would use CoreData. Pushing `UIViewController`s through touching `UITableViewCell`s can be done without code using segues. But the real problem here is that your question is too broad. Find a problem and come back with a specific question about that problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` just instantiate a new view controller, e.g. with

```
[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:identifier];
```

or just with

```
[[MyViewController alloc] init];
```

and push it onto the navigation stack.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

You can push the next controller *ad infinitum*. But please be aware of two things:

1. What you are doing is completely useless and nonsensical.
2. It could potentially take you a long time to reach the memory limit, especially on the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a physical folder, use `createDirectoryAtPath` of `NSFileManager`.  Here is the [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/createDirectoryAtPath:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:error:).

Here is an example:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *folderPath1 = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"directory1"];
NSString *folderPath = [folderPath1 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"directory2"];
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:folderPath])
{
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:folderPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"folder existed");
}
```